# onclick generates invalid function

Tags: javascript, css

I have a variable that is attached to a function. I am trying to use that variable in an onclick event.
This is what I am doing

```
var show = function() {
   console.log("hello");
};

$(container).append(
   "<div class='info' onclick=" + show + ">Show</div>"
);
```

However the generated html comes out like this

```
<div class="info" onclick="function()" {="" console.log("hello");="" }="">
     Show
</div>
```

Any idea how I can fix this so that when I click the div my function gets called ?

Comment: `show()` you missed the `()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do like this, Just make show a function and call it on click.
This will work

```
<script>
   function show() {
      console.log("hello");
   }

   $(container).append(
      '<div class="info" onclick="show()">Show</div>'
   );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `show` is a `function`, Then how can you bind it with `string`?

The code should be like,

```
$(container).append("<div class='info' onClick='show()'>Show</div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of an unusual approach to what you're trying to do. I think it would be more idiomatic in jQuery to either

a) define the element first, with event handler, and then append it,

```
$("<div>Show</div>", {
  "class": "info",
  on: {
    click: function(e) {
     console.log("Hello");
    }
  }
}).appendTo($(container));
```

or

b) append a new element and then add an event handler to it after appending it.

```
$(container).append("<div class='info'>Show</div>");
$(container).children('.info').last().on('click', function(e) { console.log("Hello"); });
```

Between those two, I'd recommend the first in this case.

Answer (score 0):

try using :

```
var show = function() {
    console.log("hello");
};

$(container).append("<div class='info' onclick="+'show()'+">Show</div>");
```

This will work. 
The reason why your code

```
var show = function() {
    console.log("hello");
};

$(container).append("<div class='info' onclick=" + show + ">Show</div>");
```

was not working as required as show is an object of type function, so when one uses the function name without the `()` the variable is replaced bu the code that it consists.
Hope it helps.